# Way for popups to be shown when using the clustering feature of QGIS2Web (Leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, clustering, qgis2web

I have been making use of the QGIS2Web Plugin (current version 3.16.0) to create interactive maps (Leaflet) with great success thus far, however I have now discovered an issue when I use the "Cluster" feature under the "Layers and Groups" setting.

When selecting this option, the points cluster as expected, however upon zooming in and attempting to click on/hover over a point to see the pop-up window to view more information that I have included, it does not appear.

I have seen through my searches that this has been a historic issue however I have not managed to find a fix as yet for myself.

Comment: clustering makes the feature disappear from the map, making it visible only at a zoom that does not overlap with other features, therefore the query with the pop-up will only work with visible features.  The only way is to turn off clustering.  Could this be a solution for you?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Just to clarify, when I am attempting to access the popups, I have zoomed in sufficiently for the feature to appear/be visible - I am not attempting to access the popups when the features are still clustered together within the numbered circle (indicating how many features are within the cluster).  It is still an issue even if I zoom in as much as possible.  Do you essentially mean that using the clustering option changes the feature to no longer be clickable/have popups and is then more of a visual representation rather than an option to convey information?

Comment: I did further tests with simple point layers, when you click on a cluster it zooms, then the highlight feature, popup on click and popup on hover all work fine. Can you create a zip with your data so I can check it?

Comment: Thank you again!  I unfortunately am unable to share a zip file due to the data being sensitive, however, I suspect the issue lies with the fact that I have created custom SVG icons for the points given that you had no issue with the clustering with a simple point layer.  I will test the issue with standard points tomorrow and respond with what I have discovered

Comment: As a follow up, I have tested the clustering again but this time using simple marker symbology for my multipoint layer.  Perhaps it will be functional if the layers have single points per feature rather than multiple as I have at the moment.  So in other words I am showing locations of different organisations' projects across a landscape so if there was one point per organisation as a feature rather than multiple points per organisation as a feature.  I will test that out too and respond with what I have discovered.

Comment: Try to understand the situation that generates your problem and report it with as much information as possible by editing the question. Thanks.